# Writing a Hex Editor in MFC

Tags: mfc, hex-editors

I intend to write a hex editor in MFC for a vertical application. The application does several things but one requirement is to view and edit raw messages in both Hex and ASCII form, just like what hex editors do.

Will it be too much work to start extending a `CView` class? Does it make sense to extend `CEdit` control?

Of course, I'll need to implement scrolling, text selection, cut-copy-paste and caret movement as the minimum required features.

Comment: In order to me woul dbe easyer to override CSCrollView

Comment: CodeProject has some grid controls and such. I haven't checked, but I'd be almost surprised if at least one of them didn't support displaying data in hex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've posted source code to do exactly this in my article [MFC Hex Editor Control](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/controls/mfc-hex-editor-control).

It's older but should be a perfect starting point for making any customizations.